# Magento 2: Paypal - I'm sorry - but we were not able to process your payment. Please try another payment method or contact us so we can assist you

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-express, magento2.1.5

While doing payment with Paypal Sandbox suddenly it gives below error

> I'm sorry - but we were not able to process your payment. Please try
>   another payment method or contact us so we can assist you.

In the log error it says

> main.CRITICAL: PayPal NVP gateway errors: Instruct the customer to
>   retry the transaction using an alternative payment method from the
>   customers PayPal wallet. The transaction did not complete with the
>   customers selected payment method (#10417: Transaction cannot
>   complete). Correlation ID: 620934b68a59c. Version: 72.0.

I tried to reenter credentials but still it gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by just changing "Transfer cart line item" to "Yes" in admin panel from path Store > configuration > sales > payment methods > PayPal express checkout > Basic setting PayPal express checkout > advance settings.

See below screenshot for details,

https://prnt.sc/ii4zll

Comment: It is already set to "Yes", still getting the same error message from Paypal. any other solution ? Thank you